# Does the name of sitemap.xml file matter for SEO (closed)

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, sitemaps

In our multi-store Magento, we have named the sitemaps as following and in Google webmaster tool we have no error. But when it comes to checking the SEO of our website through on-line tools, we get Sitemap.xml missing. Does the name of the sitemap.xml matter for SEO?

```
OurStoreViewName1_sitemap.xml
OurStoreViewName2_sitemap.xml
OurStoreViewName3_sitemap.xml
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Magento. it's about SEO in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the online tools all look for the standard sitemap.xml and therefore you sitemap.xml with the specific name will not be found from these tools.

At least I know that for some tools that is correct.

So my opinion, it does not matter.